# laravel - blank page generated on call to view

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following routes:

```
       <?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('item', 'ItemController@index');
Route::get('item/create', 'ItemController@create');
Route::get('item/{id}', 'ItemController@show');

Route::get('welcome', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

And this is what my Item controller looks like:

```
@section('content');
<h1>Add a  new item</h1>
<hr />
<content>
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::open() !!}
        {!! Form::label('name', "Name") !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</content>
```

@stopttp\Requests;

```
use App\Item;
class ItemController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    //fetch all items from the database
    $items = Item::All();
    return $items;
}

public function show($id) {

    $item = Item::FindOrFail($id);
}

public function create() {
    return view::make('item.create');
}

}
```

create.blade.phpHere is my view located at /resources/views/item/create.blade.php: @section('content');

## Add a  new item

---

{!! Form::open() !!}
            {!! Form::label('name', "Name") !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    

@stop

I am trying to load a item creation method for this laravel based e-commerce I am building. I can't seem to access the item.create view when I visit the route in the specified page, just a blank page  when I load the view; I do not see the view's HTML. Any help, please?

Heres a copy of my log files:

```
[2016-04-19 17:44:41] local.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'View [articles.create] not found.' in /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php(79): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->findInPaths('articles.create', Array)
#1 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php(165): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->find('articles.create')
#2 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(783): Illuminate\View\Factory->make('articles.create', Array, Array)
#3 /home/thomas/ushop/app/Http/Controllers/ItemController.php(25): view('articles.create')
#4 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\ItemController->create()
#5 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(80): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('create', Array)
#7 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\ItemController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'create')
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#13 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\ItemController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'create')
#14 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\Http\Contro...', 'create')
#15 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#22 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#35 /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /home/thomas/ushop/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 {main}
```

Comment: Can we see the view and where is located?

Comment: What version of Laravel is this? Blank page means you need to check your server logs for the error details.

Comment: Here is my view located at /resources/views/item/create.blade.php: @section('content');
    <h1>Add a  new item</h1>
    <hr />
    <content>
        <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::open() !!}
            {!! Form::label('name', "Name") !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </content>
</div>
@stop

Comment: This is Laravel 5. I will check the server logs.

Comment: Here are the contents of my log files:

Comment: <content>... new tag?

Comment: Yes It's an HTML5 tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You said `return view::make('item.create');`, it should be `return View::make('item.create');` or `return view('item.create');`
2. Logs and code are saying different things. Logs talk about a View [articles.create] not found, your code talks about a item.create View. Are you sure you pointing to the correct route <=> controller ? Maybe try to clear cache

Comment: That seemed to stop the blank page result, but I get another error which I'm off to research.

Comment: Can you give us more informations about your new error ? Logs ?

Comment: Laravel threw a Model not found error when I try to go to items/create. Now I''m getting a blank page agian. Here is my error log

Comment: And now when I try to load the component, I get a blank page. Any help?

Comment: I can't see your new logs, can you update your main post ?

Comment: I can't find my logs in the vendor directory. All I see in my storage/app folder are .git files. I get a blank page loading item/create.

Comment: I added the laravel.log file to my post.

Comment: Do you use apache ? nginx ? Gives your error.log, maybe we will have more infos. The bootstrap/cache and storage folder have correct rights ?

Comment: Have you checked your folder permissions

Answer (score 0):

Either you changed the view or you have a spelling error. The log says 'articles.create' not found and it really seems that you don't have that. In your case it's item.create.

If it's a spelling error, use **item**.create and not item**s**.

Answer (score 0):

because of laravel cache:clear cant remove views cache file , you should delete them by yourself . go to storage -> framework -> views  then remove all generated files manually